# Do you need to explicitly include the primary key in a composite index?

Tags: mysql, index, mariadb

I recently read that when creating a composite index in MariaDB that the primary key is appended to the end of the index "under the covers". I access my data many times in order by these four columns: `a`, `b`, `c`, and `id` (`id` being the primary key). Can I omit `id` from the CREATE INDEX statement and still enjoy retrieving data via the index in order by all 4 columns? Or should I still explicitly include `id` in the CREATE INDEX definition?

Comment: Provide a sample - CREATE TABLE, including all indices, and a query. *Can I omit id from the CREATE INDEX statement and still enjoy retrieving data via the index in order by all 4 columns?* In general - no.

Comment: 3 columns in the index doesn't imply the remaining id key is in order in that index. Note its secondary composite indexes that have a PK reference appended as the PK is a clustered index, and secondary ones aren't. Note a primary key can be composite too. Creating a [sample fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.6) with your query, and `explain {query}` will show index usage.

Comment: @danblack - I've never seen that happen, but that does not prove anything.  Have you looked at the code to see that it might actually scramble them?  I would expect creating a "temp" table of a,b,c,id, then sorting, then constructing the index BTree would be faster than sorting a,b,c, then tacking on id somehow, and finally constructing the BTree.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can definitely skip adding `id` to the `CREATE INDEX`

Let's say you already created that index with `(a,b,c,id)`

Here is how you can show that you can do with the `id` column:

Run [pt-duplicate-key-checker](https://docs.percona.com/percona-toolkit/pt-duplicate-key-checker.html) against your MySQL Instance.

Let's say you ran this

```
CREATE DATABASE IF EXISTS mydb;
USE mydb
CREATE TABLE mytable
(
    id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    a CHAR(10),
    b VARCHAR(20),
    c TINYINT
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
    KEY abc_id_ndx (a,b,c,id)
);
INSERT INTO mytable (a,b,c) VALUES ('CHAR1','VARCHAR1',1);
INSERT INTO mytable (a,b,c) VALUES ('CHAR2','VARCHAR2',2);
INSERT INTO mytable (a,b,c) VALUES ('CHAR3','VARCHAR3',3);
```

When you run [pt-duplicate-key-checker](https://docs.percona.com/percona-toolkit/pt-duplicate-key-checker.html), it will report the SQL to change that index. In fact, the recommended SQL will be something like:

```
ALTER TABLE mytable DROP INDEX abc_id_ndx, ADD INDEX abc_id_ndx (a,b,c);
```

Comment: But, who's to say that pd-dkc's suggestion is not unnecessary?

Answer (score 1):

MariaDB *might* do this but thinking more generically ...

Any secondary index *has* to have a "pointer" to the data record that it refers to.  If MariaDB uses the PK for that purpose, fine.  Other DBMSs do it differently (yes; I'm thinking of Oracle, here).

If you want to look something up by its [unique] Primary Key, then you don't need *anything else* to find it.  Just the Primary Key value will do and Primary Keys are always indexed.

If you want to look something up by any *other* value(s), then they need to be indexed.  If you *regularly* use multiple columns to do those lookups, then create a composite index on those columns (it's common for a database engine to "pick" only one index for each query).

So no; you don't need to include the Primary Key in any composite, secondary indexes.

Answer (score 0):

I like to include the PK when I depend on `id` being part of the `INDEX`; eg,  to make it "covering".  This is to clue the human reader in that I need it.  (Suppose they convert to Oracle -- The efficiency of being "covering" would get lost.)

**Bottom Line** -- Add `id` if you need it.  Else, don't worry.